# How precompile css3 include attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, sass

I have a css:

```
.answer_meta_outer {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ababab; 
  margin: 0 0 45px; 
  &:after {
    @include clr;
  } 
}
```

I got a error:

```
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined mixin 'clr'.
```

File name is app/assets/stylesheets/responsive.css

Help me fix it please :)

Comment: The error seems self explanatory to me ... clr isn't defined at the time that is being precompiled. You need to provide more information if you want help - e.g. what is the declaration for the clr mixin and where is it defined in relation to that css you have posted.

Comment: I have a file css3! No sass, no mixin.
`&:after {@include clr;}` - it is css3 code.
How i can disable sass precompile for file with extensions css?

Comment: Please could you provide a reference to use of @include declaration for pure CSS. I only know of it as a mixin declaration for sass.

Comment: Plus you're also using a parent selector `&` and nesting, last time I checked that was scss and not css3.

Comment: I don't know css :) It did another a developer. I'll quest to him.